# Why is the C# MemoryStream Constructor's parameter type byte and not byte[]

Tags: c#, constructor, parameter-passing

I looked through the MSDN documentation for the MemoryStream Class (EDIT: Here is the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh399549.aspx
.) It's constructor is specified as:

```
public MemoryStream (
         byte buffer
)
```

and has the following description:

> Initializes a new non-resizable instance of the MemoryStream class
>   based on the specified byte array
>
> Parameters
>
> *buffer*
>
> The array of unsigned bytes from which to create the current stream.

Based on this description, I would expect the syntax to be:

```
public MemoryStream (
         byte[] buffer
)
```

Why is this not the case? Thanks.

EDIT (x2): It's a typo in the .NET Micro Framework 3.0

Comment: It is definitely a typo, you can see it from the description (The array of unsigned bytes from which to create the current stream.). People at Microsoft make mistakes, too

Comment: The link you posted is for the .NET **Micro** Framework 3.0, but anyway I think it's a typo on the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Be sure to make a note with the `Community Additions` section at the bottom of the msdn page. It allows you to call out errata like this. MS employees responsible for the docs will sometimes see these and address issues when this feature is used.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx

the constructor is overloaded

Comment: There's an update to the post with the link. It wasn't the case of overloading.